# How to go about implementing prepared statements with parameters, is it even possible with this query?

Tags: php, data-binding, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I am new to MySQL and PHP, and I've built a query based on conditionals, as our database structure is a little odd. Before going any further in development, I wanted to implement the query with prepared statements using parameters to prevent injection. I watched a video that stated using real_escape_string can prevent sql injection, so my first question is, is this enough? or are parameters absolutely necessary. I sense that they are. The question following that is, is there anything wrong with the way I've implemented this, besides it being very long? Basically there is 4 drop downs in a form, and each drop down contains 5 options, the user can select 1 option from each drop down, and then submit. Using the $_POST variable, I select what I need in the best way I could think of from the database. So, if there's nothing wrong with how I've done this, then my question is, Where and how would I begin to implement prepared statements with this? I've researched it, but it is hard to understand with what I have going on. I was thinking that I would need the same if-else conditional to set the parameters, but even still I'm confused with where to place the ?. If anyone could help me I would be greatly appreciative. Thank you....The big query is below:

Also, getHourValue() returns an additional string with a query seqment depending on the value in $_POST['hours'], because it was an extremely long segment that's used over and over, I put it in a function.

```
            if($_POST['category'] == "anywhere") {
                if($_POST['food'] == "No") {
                    if($_POST['extra'] == "anything") {
                        $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE (food LIKE '%Yes%' " . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . ") 
                        OR (food LIKE '%No%' " . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . ")";
                    }
                    else if($_POST['extra'] == "everything") {
                        $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE (food LIKE '%Yes%' AND pool LIKE '%Yes%' AND dancing LIKE '%Yes%' AND tv LIKE '%Yes%' "
                                . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . ") OR (food LIKE '%No%'
                                AND pool LIKE '%Yes%' AND dancing LIKE '%Yes%' AND tv LIKE '%Yes%' "
                                . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . ")";
                    }
                    else {
                        $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE (food LIKE '%Yes%' AND " . $_POST['extra'] . " LIKE '%Yes%' " . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) .") 
                        OR (food LIKE '%No%' AND " . $_POST['extra'] . " LIKE '%Yes%' " . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . ")";
                    }
                }
                else if($_POST['extra'] == "anything") {
                    $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE food LIKE '%Yes%' "
                            . getHourValue($_POST['hours']);
                }
                else if($_POST['extra'] == "everything") {
                    $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE food LIKE '%Yes%'
                            AND pool LIKE '%Yes%' AND dancing LIKE '%Yes%' AND tv LIKE '%Yes%' " 
                            . getHourValue($_POST['hours']);
                }
                else { 
                    $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE food LIKE '%Yes%' 
                            AND " . $_POST['extra'] . " LIKE '%Yes%' "
                            . getHourValue($_POST['hours']);
                }
            }
            else {
                if($_POST['food'] == "No") {
                    if($_POST['extra'] == "anything") {
                        $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE (category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%' " . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . "
                                AND food LIKE '%Yes%') OR (category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%' " . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . " AND food LIKE '%No%')";

                    }
                    else if($_POST['extra'] == "everything") {
                        $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE (category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%'"
                                . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . " AND food LIKE '%Yes%' AND pool LIKE '%Yes%' AND dancing LIKE '%Yes%' AND tv LIKE '%Yes%') 
                                OR (category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%'"  
                                . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . " AND food LIKE '%No%' AND pool LIKE '%Yes%' AND dancing LIKE '%Yes%' AND tv LIKE '%Yes%')";
                    }
                    else {
                        $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE (category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%' "
                            . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . " AND food LIKE '%Yes%' AND " . $_POST['extra'] . " LIKE '%Yes%') OR (category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%' " . getHourValue($_POST['hours']) . " 
                            AND food LIKE '%No%' AND " . $_POST['extra'] . " LIKE '%Yes%')";
                    }
                }
                else if($_POST['extra'] == "anything") {
                    $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%'
                            AND food LIKE '%Yes%' "
                            . getHourValue($_POST['hours']);
                }
                else if($_POST['extra'] == "everything") {
                    $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%'
                            AND food LIKE '%Yes%' AND pool LIKE '%Yes%' AND dancing LIKE '%Yes%' AND tv LIKE '%Yes%' "
                            . getHourValue($_POST['hours']);
                }
                else {
                    $sql = "SELECT name, description FROM pubs WHERE category LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "%'
                            AND food LIKE '%Yes%' AND " . $_POST['extra'] . " LIKE '%Yes%' "
                            . getHourValue($_POST['hours']);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably create some sort of query builder (or use an existing one from a framework). Adding the prepared statements in your above code make it more complicated (although that is not an excuse).

Example: You collect all conditions in an array, inject placeholders for each, then on PDO Statement, bind the values.

NOTE: Below is not tested.

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT name, description FROM pubs';
$where = [];
$params = [];

// If condition
// then add it to where
// $where[] = '(field1 = :field1)';
// $params[':field1'] = $_POST['field1'];

// If another condition
// then add to where
// $where[] = 'field2 = :field2';
// $params[':field2'] = $_POST['field2'];

// Combine where conditions (you may need to implement both AND and OR)
if (!empty($where)) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);
}

// Assuming this is your pdo object
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

// Bind your parameter values
if (!empty($params)) {
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $statement->bindValue($key, $value, \PDO::_PARAM_STR);
    }
}

// Then fetch the records
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
```